# Getting plain english from choice field in template

Tags: django, django-models

I have this in my model:

```
BEHV = (
    ('E', 'Externalizer'),
    ('I', 'Internalizer'),
)
# E or I ?
behavior_type = models.CharField(max_length=1, choices=BEHV)
```

And this in my template:

```
{{ s.behavior_type }}
```

Which renders

```
E
```

But I want it to render,

```
Externalizer
```

Instead. Is there I way to do this without swapping the tuples around in `BEHV`?

Answer (score 4):

Just do this:

```
{{ s.get_behavior_type_display }}
```

Comment: Relevant Docs: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.6/ref/models/instances/#django.db.models.Model.get_FOO_display